# Visual Studio Code Compare (for merging) for CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, merge

In Visual Studio 2010 the code comparison tool used when merging changes is not very good when trying to merge CSS and JS files.

Any suggestions on a good third-party merge tool that works well with CSS and JS files and that we can integrate with VS2010?

Comment: git. it's really a saviour once you're used to it

Comment: I think he meant git and not github.. anyway, check [this](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs)

Comment: How does this help with making file comparisons easier when checking in CSS/JS files?

Comment: Beyond Compare is what we use. It's excellent.

Comment: I didn't say anything about github...I also use Beyond Compare, its a great GUI tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) is free, open-source, and Just Works.

Please see [Change Visual Studio Compare Tool To WinMerge](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2011/06/01/change-visual-studio-compare-tool-to-winmerge.aspx) for instructions on how to set-up VS2010 to use WinMerge.

And here are [notes on getting VS (Team System) 2008 to use WinMerge.](http://blog.paulbouwer.com/2010/01/31/replace-diffmerge-tool-in-visual-studio-team-system-with-winmerge/)

If you're using VisualSourceSafe (ugh), you need some [additional configuration.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4258496/41153)

Answer (score 2):

Devart Code Compare:

http://www.devart.com/codecompare/

Answer (score 1):

BeyondCompare is excellent (though paid for):

http://www.scootersoftware.com/index.php

And has intructions for integrating with TFS:
http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs#tfs

n.b. I don't work for scooter software, I'm just a fan. My work has a group license, so depends if you want to pay for it.

Though I've also used WinMerge in the past and I'm a fan of that to.

Comment: I also highly recommend BeyondCompare, for me it is definitely worth its cost.